# Why is my React/JSX if statement still executing?

Tags: reactjs, if-statement, jsx

I have a contact form that I'm looking to prevent submittal on if there is no entry in any of the following form inputs:  name, email, and/or message.  The form continues to fire, though, under the current syntax even with one of the refs coming up blank.  Having trouble determining why?

```
submit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
    (this.refs.name.value  === "" || this.refs.email.value === "" || 
    this.refs.message.value === "")  
?
    alert("Sorry.  Message not submitted.  Form requires Name, Email, 
    & Message.")
:
    this.setState({
    modalIsOpen: true,
    }) 
    axios({
     method: "POST", 
     url:"/submit", 
     data: {
      name: this.refs.name.value,   
      email: this.refs.email.value,  
      message: this.refs.message.value
     }
   })};
```

Comment: Could you share the render method?

Comment: Also, another comment, I wouldn't recommend using `ref` because React doesn't recommend it, I would rather store the data you want in the state of the component

Comment: Thanks, Mayhem!  I am exporting as the 'Contact' form component to a parent app.js file where the component is rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the ternary operator, you only get one statement for each side of the if-else block. Your `axios` call is going to happen regardless of the if, because the else side of the ternary is your `this.setState` call. The `axios` call is a separate statement in JavaScript and thus not part of the ternary. This is a situation where JavaScript's relaxation on semicolons can bite you and linters can become your best friend.

```
submit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (this.refs.name.value === "" || this.refs.email.value === "" || this.refs.message.value === "") {
    alert("Sorry.  Message not submitted.  Form requires Name, Email, & Message.")
  } else {
    this.setState({ modalIsOpen: true });
    axis.get({
      method: "POST", 
      url: "/submit", 
      data: {
        name: this.refs.name.value,   
        email: this.refs.email.value,  
        message: this.refs.message.value
      }
    });
  }
  // <- Your axios call was going here instead. That is why it always submitted
};
```

Also, as Mayhem mentioned in the comments, you would be better off storing the values of name, email, and message in the state and update them via `onChange` events. This way, you can grab the values from the state instead. There are several other benefits to this, including that your render is always in sync with your state (deterministic render is a great feature of React).

Comment: Works beautifully...thank you!  Didn't realize conventional JS if statements worked inside React components.  Lesson learned.  Thank you!!